# How to calculate Hours and minutes using Business Hours?

Tags: apex, trigger, businesshours

I have used this to calculate hours , but minutes part is not getting covered.

```
long businessMillisecondsDiff = BusinessHours.diff(bh.Id,cs.CreatedDate,system.now());
decimal businessHoursDiff = businessMillisecondsDiff / (1000.0*60.0*60.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

It does give you both, you just get minutes as a fraction of hours. If you want minutes only, you can just divide by 60:

```
Decimal businessMinutesDiff = calculatedDiff / (1000*60);
```

Or, if you want whole hours and the number of remainder minutes:

```
Decimal businessMinutesDiff = calculatedDiff / (1000*60);
Decimal hours = businessHours.divide(60).round(RoundingMode.DOWN);
Decimal minutes = businessMinutesDiff - 60 * hours;
```

Comment: On the same field we want to show both hours and minutes. will it be possible   ?

Comment: What's the field type? Text? It should be pretty obvious how to take these last two `Decimal` values and generate a `String`.

Comment: No the field type is number,  Length is have given as 10 and decimal 2 .

Comment: So just save the original `businessHoursDiff` in that...everything after the decimal will be the fraction of a minute elapsed.

Comment: Er...fraction of an hour. So 1.5 business hours elapsed is the sam as 1 hour, 30 minutes.

Comment: Yeah got it :) Thanks again . May be i should change it to string. will check :)